# Normalising accelerometer data

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I've been trying for a long time to try to figure out why the way my game plays varies slightly differently on different devices (i.e.: some devices seem to be more sensitive than others with regards to the accelerometers).

I've just noticed that the when tilting my devices and logging the output, on one device, the output seems to be between -9.5 and + 9.5 and on another, it appears to be around -10.7 to +10.7.
I'm using this returned data to move my sprite.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {        
    tiltAmount = event.values[device_rotation];
    Log.v("Tag", "Value: " + tiltAmount);
}
```

In the above code example, as I'm tilting the device to the opposite extremes (90° anti-clockwise and 90° clockwise), I'm getting the ranges described above.

I would like this data to be consistent across device.

Does anyone have any idea how I could normalise it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have extreme values defined. In that scenario, you could divide a given value by the total dynamic range to get normalized value:

```
NormalizedValue = x / (Highest - Lowest)
```

Comment: Hi @Learner, just a couple of things, with the answer you have give (If I'm understanding it correctly), I would be doing something like: normalisedValue = x / (10 - -10); (if of course, the range was -10 to +10) which would equate to normalisedValuie = x/(20)?? Just wanted to confirm I was understanding this correctly.  The main problem is of course, that I only have the range values because I plugged in the device and tilted it while logging the output!!  I.e. I don't have this information at run time.